# Error opening webpage from Excel VBA, but same address works when manually pasting in browser

Tags: vba, excel

I just discovered a strange error when executing a VBA code opening webpages in a browser. In the Excel model I have several IDs for different funds and I want to open all the webpages with information about these funds. The webpages all have the same adress, except from the IDs at the end of the address.

The code is actually kind of working. It tries to open all of the pages, BUT I'm getting redirected to "https://companyadress.com/" even do pasting the same address string in an empty tab in my browser manually takes me to the correct location.

The code looks as follows:

```
Dim numFunds As Integer
numFunds = FundData.Range("fdNumFunds")

Dim webpage As String, webpageFull As String
Dim fundID As String
Dim i As Integer

webpage = "https://fund.companyadress.com/"

For i = 1 To numFunds

    fundID = FundData.Range("fdFundsTopLeft")(i, 2)
    webpageFull = webpage & fundID

    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink _
      Address:=webpageFull, NewWindow:=False

Next i
```

Thankful if someone have a clue what goes wrong when trying to open the pages from Excel. I think it must have something to do with how Excel paste the address in the browser.

Comment: You probably have an unexpected (invisible) character in the cell.

Comment: Hi Nick. Doesn't seem that way. When pasting the adress to the workbook and follow that link the same thing happens. But when pasting the same link in for instance an email and follow it from there gets me to the correct webpage. Excel is doing something strange.

Comment: What about pasting into an internet shortcut (right click / new shortcut)

Comment: Same problem. When pressing the link the webpage checks if you're logged in to the company's webpage. Something must go wrong here, when going via an email in Outlook everything works as planned.